# custom runtime_error, if I use #c_str() in #what, the error output are always empty

Tags: c++, c++11

following is my code, I'm sure when std::string, the string(s2) has value

```
class StdErr : public std::runtime_error {
public:

    std::string msg;

    StdErr(const std::string &m) : runtime_error(m) {
        this->msg = m;
    }

    const char *what() const throw() {
        std::string s = "appended msg";
        std::string s2 = ((std::string) "prpr" + "\n" + s);
        return s2.c_str();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    throw StdErr("prpr");
    return (0);
};
```

but the output always "what:(empty message)", like following

```
/home/roroco/Dropbox/c/ro-c/cmake-build-debug/ex/test_stderr_what_with_newline
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'StdErr'
  what():  
Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I hope when throw StdErr, it can output my appended message, how to do?

update, I find the alternative solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614113/return-a-dynamic-string-from-stdexceptions-what), but I still confuse, I think `return "msg"` and `std::string s = "msg"; return s.c_str();` are same, why throw error message is diff?

Comment: Undefined behavior. You return a pointer to the memory location, that is destroyed upon exiting `what`.

Comment: Your code can be fixed by changing to `return "prpr" "\n" "appended msg";`

Comment: @melpomene yes, return a "content" work, but it cannot be used in all case, I need append string varaible to message

Comment: Well, AlgirdasPreidžius told you what's wrong with your current code. If you want a better solution, show us a better example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: No, they're not "the same". One returns a pointer to a string constant. The other returns a pointer to internal data from an object that gets destroyed, making the returned pointer invalid. The exception gets thrown because of an attempt to dereference an invalid pointer. Undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the memory that the returned `char*` points to still exists after your method goes out of scope. One way is to store `s2` as member in your class:

```
class StdErr : public std::runtime_error {
public:

    std::string msg;
    std::string s2;

    StdErr(const std::string &m) : runtime_error(m) {
        this->msg = m;
    }

    const char *what() const throw() {
        std::string s = "appended msg";
        s2 = "prpr" + "\n" + s;
        return s2.c_str();
    }
};
```

Comment: @downvoter Let me know what's wrong with this answer, I am always eager to learn.